# CodeIgniter Route pass param in default route

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

Suppose I have developed a website www.example.com, 
Now I want to pass a param just after the domain name. e.g. www.example.com/param. Is that possible?

My defult route

Comment: Yes it is possible, I would recommend starting with the tutorial here to figure out how parameters and routing works: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url(). "?params=your-parameter"?>">Click</a>

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the parameter to default route like following.

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages'; 
$route['about'] = 'pages/about'; 
$route['(.*)'] = 'pages';
```

You should call `$route['(.*)']` in the last line of the code, else if you type `www.example.com/about` **About Page** URL in the browser, it will redirect to `default controller` method.

`$route['(.*)']` : it means you can pass unlimited param in the URL

use can use `$this->uri->segment()` or `$this->uri->segment_array()` to collection the paramaters in the function

*example:*
If your URL like this

> www.example.com/param1/param2/param3/param4

```
public function index(){
    $param1 = $this->uri->segment(1); // return `param1`
    $param2 = $this->uri->segment(2); // return `param2`
    $param3 = $this->uri->segment(3); // return `param3`
    $param4 = $this->uri->segment(4); // return `param4`

    // OR
    $paramArray = $this->uri->segment_array(4); // all parameter in Array format
}
```